# Copy and paste and keep hidden after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me on this code. All I want is to copy a data and paste it to cell and keep it hidden. But after using my code and pasting it, still visible. How can I make a **vba code** that after pasting, it will hide the cell? Please help me. Thanks.

```
Sub selectVisibleRange()
   Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
   Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
   Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

   DbExtract.Range("X:X").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
   DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't copying hidden cells. You're copying visible cells.

Comment: If you hide all the visible cells in column X there is nothing left on the worksheet,

Comment: I know now the answer to my question. 


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   
    Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
    Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    DbExtract.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    
    End Sub

Comment: Why are you pasting the column widths and then hiding the column? paste:=8 is paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths.

Answer (score 0):

I know now the answer to my question..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

DbExtract.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
DuplicateRecords.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True


End Sub
```